# where does org-plot output go in emacs-29?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs-plus@29 on macos (native compilation),

org-plot does not seem to do show anything, e.g. on this input:

```
  #+PLOT: title:"Citas" ind:1 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
 | Sede      | Max cites | H-index |
 |-----------+-----------+---------|
 | Chile     |    257.72 |   21.39 |
 | Leeds     |    165.77 |   19.68 |
 | Sao Paolo |     71.00 |   11.50 |
 | Stockholm |    134.19 |   14.33 |
 | Morelia   |    257.56 |   17.67 |
```

It does create an output file when I specify it (even if that takes a while). But I was expecting a window or buffer to open when I don't specify an output file, but nada, zilch.

The`*gnuplot*` buffer does show something like:

```
gnuplot> reset
gnuplot> set title 'Citas'
gnuplot> set yrange [0:]
gnuplot> set datafile separator "\t"
gnuplot> plot '/var/folders/gs/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/T/org-plotBeef' using 3:xticlabel(1) with histograms title 'H-index'
gnuplot>
```

I suspect this is due to the cutting edge nature of emacs-plus29, but if someone has an idea of what could be going on, I'd hugely appreciate a hint.

Comment: Works just fine for me with Emacs 29 (current from git as of a few days ago).

Comment: So what *should* happen ? A new gnuplot window ?

Comment: I get a graphics window popping up. Not sure what you mean by a "gnuplot window" but yes, if so.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought would happen, too. In my case, nothing happens. Babel code blocks like plantuml work fine though, so whatever I experience seems to be mostly gnuplot specific.

Comment: Are you sure the gnuplot window is not hiding behind your emacs window? You can also run `gnuplot` interactively and give it all the commands you find in the `*gnuplot*` buffer, but unfortunately the temporary file with the data is deleted using an idle time in `org-plot.el`. You can either disable that (I commented out line 675 in my org-gnuplot.el which reads `(run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil #'delete-file data-file)`) or you can cobble together your own data file the way that `org-plot` would do it: get rid of the `|` chars, add double quotes around all the numbers and use TAB as a separator.

Comment: In case it's not clear: that's a debugging suggestion.